# Java Interfaces Casting

Tags: java, interface, casting

Imagine we have class C that implements interfaces I and J declared as ;

```
I i = new C();
```

why do these 3 not give errors (especially the last one):

```
1) C c = (C)i;
2) J j = (J)i;
3) i   = (I)null;
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post `C` signature?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Based on question I think we can safely assume that it is `class C implements I,J{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `C c = (C)i;`

   Since `i` can hold instance of type `C` there is no problem with allowing by compiler casting `I` to `C` type reference (if casting will succeed at runtime we will be sure that all methods from `C` reference will be supported by instance which will also be of type `C` or its subtype).
2. `J j = (J)i;`

   Since there is a possibility (like in our case) that instance stored in `i` will also implement `J` interface *compilers* allows us to cast between references of unrelated interfaces. But if instance stored in `i` will not implement `J` then we will get `ClassCastException` at *runtime*.
3. `i   = (I)null;`

   Well, `null` can be assigned to *any* reference so there is no problem with allowing it to be assigned to `i` or cast it.

Answer (score 0):

The first one works, because i is an instance of C (even if the reference is of type I, but for the casting the reference type is irrelevant).

The second works, because i is an instance of C and thus also an instance of J (since C implements J). The reference type is irrelevant for casting.

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces is a different "view" from the object. When you debug it, there is always the "C" object.

For Null you can look here:
[No Exception while type casting with a null in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723596/no-exception-while-type-casting-with-a-null-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

1. Works because *i* is a reference variable of *I*, but that holds an instance of *C*. You're allowed to downcast an object if the object is an instance of the class you're casting to.
2. *C* implements *J* and you're always allowed to upcast an object.
3. I guess it's becuase *i* is a reference variable, which is allowed to have a null value, and you're giving it a value of null.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the object and assigned it to i with the statement.

```
    I i = new C();
```

The object is still a C even though the variable refering to it is defined as I.

SO

```
    C c = (C)i;
```

just assigns the same object to a new variable that is defined as C. And as the object is of type C there is no problem.

```
    j = (J)i;
```

just assigns the same object to a new variable that is defined as J. And as the object is of type C which implements the interface J  it is also of type J so there is no problem.

```
    i   = (I)null;
```

Just sets the variable i to null.