# Null is casted in decompiled java class file

Tags: java, decompiler, .class-file

I decompiled one of my java .class files and saw this line of code

```
new ResponseModel("Reset Complete", false, (LinkedHashMap)null)
```

The line corresponds to

```
new ResponseModel("Reset Complete", false, null);
```

Why was the null parameter casted? Is it just my decompiler hinting the parameter type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Exception while type casting with a null in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723596/no-exception-while-type-casting-with-a-null-in-java)

Comment: @Kaustubh Khara, it's not the same. I saw that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immagine you've overloaded a method:

```
public class Foo {

    public void something (String s) { ... }
    public void something (List l) { ... }
}
```

Invoking `something` with a `null` argument is now **ambiguous**.
To **bind** the invocation to either method, you need to **cast the null value**, giving it a type:

```
new Foo().something((String)null);
new Foo().something((List)null);
```

As this **class may be different at runtime than on compile time** (on compile time, the method may not be overloaded, but on runtime the class is a newer version which has an overloaded method), the compiler makes it **explicit** in the bytecode to prevent ambiguousness later.